# Library Linking with compositor and VSE

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, blend-files, linked-data

Let's say I have the characters linked to a scene named "Shot_002" in Shot_002.blend where I did the animation. I can link the Scene to a new .blend file and use it in the compositor, or I can link the same Scene to another .blend file and use it in the VSE.
Is there a way to link the file with the compositing work to a file with the editing work to make a render of the full short film directly after the editing is complete?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you do have recently opened files listed in File->Open Recent.

There is the [Edit Linked Library](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Edit_Linked_Library) addon that adds buttons to switch back and forth between linked mesh object files, but at this stage it doesn't support VSE strips. You may want to make a suggestion to the author or use it to make a similar addon for the VSE.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use scene strips of currently open scenes (linked or appended into the current VSE .blend file). You cannot appends a scene in directly to the VSE.